# Looping Switch Menu in C

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I improved the switch statement and i have everything working except if i want to pick another option it just repeats the print statements instead of me picking another category. So basically it only loops once. Before i used an if statement to see if the person would like to enter another category but now i added the exit function so a user can stop entering .

```
while (1)
{
printf("Please enter the corresponding number to the the category on the list\n");
printf("===========\n");
printf("1.Beverage\n2.Pastry\n3.Canned Goods\n4.Dairy\n5.Baking Goods\n6.Frozen Goods\n7.Meat\n8.Produce\n9.Cleaners\n10.Paper Goods\n11.Personal Care\n12.Other\n13.Save and Exit\n\n");
printf("Enter the number here: ");
scanf("%d",&Num);
printf("\n\n");

 switch(Num){

case 1:
for(a=0;Stop!=0;a++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[a].Beverage);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[a].BeverageNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 2:
for(b=0;Stop!=0;b++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[b].Pastry);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[b].PastryNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 3:
for(c=0;Stop!=0;c++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[c].CannedGoods);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[c].CannedGoodsNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 4:
for(d=0;Stop!=0;d++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[d].Dairy);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[d].DairyNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 5:
for(e=0;Stop!=0;e++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[e].BakingGoods);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[e].BakingGoodsNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 6:
for(f=0;Stop!=0;f++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[f].FrozenGoods);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[f].FrozenGoodsNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 7:
for(g=0;Stop!=0;g++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[g].Meat);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[g].MeatNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 8:
for(h=0;Stop!=0;h++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[h].Produce);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[h].ProduceNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 9:
for(i=0;Stop!=0;i++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[i].Cleaners);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[i].CleanersNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 10:
for(j=0;Stop!=0;j++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[j].PaperGoods);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[j].PaperGoodsNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 11:
for(k=0;Stop!=0;k++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[k].PersonalCare);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[k].PersonalCareNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;

case 12:
for(l=0;Stop!=0;l++){
printf("Please Enter Item Name\n");
scanf("%s",Items[l].Other);
printf("Please Enter The Amount of Each Item\n");
scanf("%d",&ItemsNum[l].OtherNum);
printf("Would you like to enter another item if yes type 1  if not type 0\n");
scanf("%d",&Stop);}
break;


case 13:
  printf("\n\n\t\t\tThanks for your time!\n\n\n");
                exit(0);

        }
```

Comment: I don't see any `if` statements in the code. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You're `break`ing every `for` loop at the end of first iteration. And propably you mean `case` statement instead of `if`

Comment: Move the `break` instruction out of the loop!

Comment: Move the "category" question out of the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the break statements out of the for loops and into the switch. You are breaking the forloop not the switch. Your for loops for each case are only ever going to execute once and then move to the next case because of where you put the break. 
change the statements from

```
case NUM:
for(a=0;Stop!=0;a++){
//doing prompts
break;
}
```

to

```
case NUM:
for(a=0;Stop!=0;a++){
//doing prompts
}break; //break stops the switch preventing the default from being executed incorrectly
```

Also you can just say `while(Hault);` at the end of your do while loop.

Comment: Thank you but i have run into a new problem my loop statement seems to not work and i also tried changing it to `while(Hault):` but to no luck it does not work.